# Contour integral for unbounded operators

Tags: operator-theory, contour-integration

For a bounded self-adjoint operator $A$ and a function $f$ analytic in a neighbourhood of $\sigma(A)$, we have
$$
f(A) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_\gamma f(z) \, (z-A)^{-1} \, dz,
$$
where $\gamma$ is a contour going once around the spectrum of $A$, in counter-clockwise direction. Does something similar hold for unbounded operators? And if yes, how do I have to choose the contour?

Comment: Good question. [This paper](http://www.eweb.unex.es/eweb/extracta/Vol-24-2/24J2Batty.pdf) has a nice introduction that may help you.